# RegionPlot from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, regions

I am having quite a headache using `RegionPlot` to see the region of acceptance of certain coupled differential equation. I shall elaborate and try to be as elucidating as I can.

Algorithm:

1. Vary the initial condition (`y` and `M`) for `lh` and `ls` at `t==0`,
2. Solve the coupled differential equation for the initial condition,
3. Determine the region of acceptance using `RegionPlot` by varying the initial conditions.

The code I wrote for solving the coupled differential equation is:

```
v = 246;
lh1 = M^2/(2*v^2) + (M^2 - v^2/3)*(Sin[y]/v^2);(*initial condition*)
ls1 = (v^2/M^2)*((1 - Sin[y])/Sin[2*y]);(*initial condition*)
ode3[t_, y_, M_] := 
 Module[{sol1}, 
  sol1 = NDSolve[{Dt[lh[t], t] == lh[t]^2 + (1/8) ls[t]^2 - 3/8, 
     Dt[ls[t], t] == 2 ls[t]^2 + lh[t]^2/8, lh[0] == lh1, 
     ls[0] == ls1}, {lh, ls}, {t,0,40}]; {lh[t], ls[t]} /. sol1]
```

Next step is to determine the region of acceptance for `lh` using RegionPlot. So i wrote:

```
RegionPlot[ode3[t,y,M][[1]] > 0, {y, 0.1, Pi/3}, {M, 0, 100}]
```

But I am getting an error:

```
 At t == 5.063724831935721`*^-11, step size is effectively zero; \
    singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

So can anyone help me with this problem? I want to find the region between `M` and `Sin[y]`, for all those scenarios when `lh[t]>0`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your integration range is `{t, 10, 40}` but your initial conditions are at zero.  Almost certainly, this will cause problems.  Please consider revising.  Also, be aware that your problem is with `NDSolve`, not `RegionPlot`, as can be seen from a single evaluation of `ode3`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  There's nothing wrong with that per se; `NDSolve` is built to handle that. To the OP: The problem is that `DSolve[{Derivative[1][ls][t] == 2 ls[t]^2, ls[0] == ls0}, {ls}, t]` has a pole `1/(2 ls0)` and the OP's ODE grows even faster. One really needs to ask oneself whether the ODE is stiff or has a singularity. Stiffness can sometimes be dealt with, but an infinite singularity is an inherent obstruction in the model.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks for the clarification on the initial  conditions.  I suppose that `NDSolve` just integrates from `t = 0`.  In any case, I just ran the problem with boundary conditions of `0.1` at `t = 10` and encountered a singularity at about `14.2`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes that is indeed true. There's appears to be a pole. However, if I were to use any other differential equation, that doesn't have a pole per se, but it's initial condition varies similar to this question, how can I make use of RegionPlot to visualize the region of acceptance? I have been struggling to use the idea of Numerical solutions of ODE's to RegionPlot effectively.

Comment: (1) You should evaluate `ode3[t,y,M][[1]]` by itself for some test values of `y` and `M`. You get a list of two interpolating functions evaluated at the symbol `t`. So `ode3[t,y,M][[1]] > 0` won't make sense. (2) Consequently, I don't know what the comparison is meant to be and I don't know what a "region of acceptance" is, except in statistics. (3) The left over symbol `t` is problem if you're going to compare something, which has to be a number, with zero. What is `t`? Is some function positive **for all** `t` or **for some** `t`? I see bbgodfrey made `t` equal to `11` -- is that reasonable?

Comment: In other words, aside from answering about the singularity, I don't know exactly what you're asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @MichaelE2: Let me enunciate. The initial conditions(IC) for lh and ls, in the above example are dependent on two variables, y and M. For one specific value of y and M each, I get one IC for lh and ls, say lh[0]==0.1 and ls[0]=0.01. Based on this initial condition I can evaluate the coupled ODE once using NDSolve. lh[t], is a function of 't' which is an arbitrary scale. Upon solving the ODE's lh[t] for the above IC's, I can see how lh[t] varies with 't', where 't' is scale. [Read next comment for completion]

Comment: @MichaelE2: Similarly by varying 'y' and 'M' for another value i get a different IC. Every time I vary the IC, i get a plot between "lh[t] vs t". So, I want to draw a Region between 'y' and 'M' for which lh[t]>0, at all scale 't' (which in here is given by {t,0,40}). IN other words, if for one IC, lh[t]<0 at any scale 't', I don't want to accept that particular 'y' and 'M' value. Have I made it any clear? 
The condition lh[t]>0 at all scale 't' will be valid for some IC. I want to determine the region between 'y' and 'M' for those IC's.

Comment: Yes, it clearer. In your code you compare `{lh[t], ls[t]} > 0` but you want `lh[t] > 0`.  Ah, I see at the end of your question you mention it. Perhaps I was confused by the code to know what you meant. By "all scale t" you mean all `t` from `t == 0` to `t == 40`, but if there is a pole in `0 < t < 40`, is it ok (included in the region if `lh[t] > 0`) or not? It seems bbgodfrey in nearly there except for the "all t" part, right?  He does only `t == 11`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Well broadly speaking, my actual equations are quite complicated, but they don't have poles. What I wanted was the RegionPlot definition. How do i define my RegionPlot such that the algorithm I mentioned earlier, gives me the desired result i.e the region between y and M, for all scale t from t==0 to t==40.

Comment: @SubhojitSarkar I hope I've interpreted your wishes correctly in my answer.  I think the "for all t" part of the problem should be added to the question.  And having an ODE system that can't really be used because of the poles is a significant distraction, I think.  If you do update your question, we should probably delete our discussion, as it has gotten rather long. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using `RegionPlot`

As I understand the problem from the comments, we have a function `f` that depends on three variables `t`, `y`, and `M` (for now we will ignore *how* it depends on these variables).  We would like to plot the region in the `{y, M}` plane where the function is positive for all `t` in the interval from `0` to `40`.  In other words, we desire the region where the **minimum** of the function is positive.  The basic idea is comprised in the pseudocode

```
RegionPlot[MinValue[{f[t, y, M], {0 <= t <= 40}] > 0, {y, 0.1, Pi/3}, {M, 0, 100}]
```

Potentially, doing many global minimizations would be time-consuming. The particular function the OP is interested in has some ways to speed up the minimization.

#### The OP's type of function

The OP's function is the solution `lh[t]` of a system of differential equations that depend on parameters `y` and `M`.  The DE in the original question has poles in `0 <= t <= 40`, but I understand from comments that the OP's actual DE does not.  Consequently, I altered the OP's so that it can be integrated and still demonstrate the solution to the basic problem stated above.

Perhaps one of the nicest approaches is to minimize `lh` within `NDSolve` while it is being integrated.  This can be done by using `WhenEvent` to update a variable `lhmin` that keeps track of the least local minimum found so far.  We have to initialize `lhmin` to the initial value at `t == 0` and finalize it by updating it if necessary with the final value at `t == 40`.  The initialization and finalization made [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) seem awkward to me, so I used `NDSolve` and cached the solutions and minima as they are found.

Note that to make `lhmin[y, M]` behave like a function, it calls `ode3`, which computes and stores its value.  After `ode3` has computed it, `lhmin[y, M]` contains this value, which is returned.

```
ClearAll[ode3, lh1, ls1, lhmin, y, M, v, t, lh, ls];
v = 246;

  (*initial conditions - modified slightly *)
lh1[y0_, M0_] := 16 M0^2/(2*v^2) + (M0^2 - v^2/3) * (Sin[y0] / v^2);
ls1[y0_, M0_] := (v^2/M0^2) * ((1 - Sin[y0]) / Sin[2*y0]);

ode3[y_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] :=
  Block[{t},
    ode3[y, M] = First @ NDSolve[{
       Dt[lh[t], t] == -ls[t]/2 - (lh[t] - 1)^3/4,         (* the basic DEs are changed *)
       Dt[ls[t], t] == lh[t]/2 - ls[t]^3,
       lh[0] == (lhmin[y, M] = lh1[y, M]),                 (* initialize lhmin[y, M] *)
       ls[0] == ls1[y, M],
       WhenEvent[lh'[t] > 0,                               (* update lhmin[y, M] at loc. min. *)
        lhmin[y, M] = Min[lhmin[y, M], lh[t]]]},
      {lh, ls}, {t, 0, 40}]; 
    lhmin[y, M] = Min[lhmin[y, M], lh[40] /. ode3[y, M]];  (* finalize lhmin[y, M] *)
    ode3[y, M]
    ];

lhmin[y0_?NumericQ, M0_?NumericQ] := (ode3[y0, M0]; lhmin[y0, M0]);
```

Plot the region:

```
RegionPlot[
  lhmin[y, M] > 0, {y, 0.1, Pi/3}, {M, $MachineEpsilon, 100}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Remark: Other ways

`NDSolve` returns an interpolating function that contains a table of values of the function.  The code

```
lh["ValuesOnGrid"] /. ode3[y, M]
```

returns this table of values.  So

```
lhmin[y0_?NumericQ, M0_?NumericQ] := Min[lh["ValuesOnGrid"] /. ode3[y, M]]
```

approximates the minimum of the function. It may be sufficiently accurate for many purposes.  If this definition is used and the `WhenEvent` code is omitted, it is slightly faster in the example of this answer.  Alternatively, it can be used to give a starting point to `FindMinimum`.  The value of `t` corresponding to the minimum value in the table is given by

```
With[{minPos = First@Ordering[lh["ValuesOnGrid"] /. ode3[y, M], 1]},
 (lh["Coordinates"] /. sol)[[1, minPos]]
 ]
```

**Caveat**: `FindMinimum` does not seem to play nice with `RegionPlot` (V10.0.1, MacOSX 10.9.5); see [Bug in plotting function using FindMinimum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69669/bug-in-plotting-function-using-findminimum).  To plot the region, use `ContourPlot` instead:

```
ContourPlot[lhmin[y, M], {y, 0.1, Pi/3}, {M, 0, 100},
  Contours -> {0},
  ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{y, M, min}, min >= 0]]
```

Answer (score 5):

I have simplified somewhat the problem to be solved by specifying initial conditions as numbers at `t = 10`:

```
ode[lh0_, ls0_] := {lh[t], ls[t]} /. 
  First@NDSolve[{Dt[lh[t], t] == lh[t]^2 + (1/8) ls[t]^2 - 3/8, 
  Dt[ls[t], t] == 2 ls[t]^2 + lh[t]^2/8, lh[10] == lh0, ls[10] == ls0}, {lh, ls}, {t, 10, 40}]
```

The result is an`InterpolatingFunction` for each of `lh` and `ls`.  Where the sign of, say, `lh` is positive at a particular value of `t` can be determined by

```
ContourPlot[(ode[x, y][[1]] /. t -> 11), {y, 0, .45}, {x, 0, .45}, 
 Contours -> {-1, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> Function[{z}, Hue[.3 (1 + Sign[z])]]]
```

[image: Contour Plot]

`lh` is positive in the blue region.

On the other hand, I was unable to do the same with `RegionPlot`

```
RegionPlot[(ode[x, y] /. t -> 11) > 0, {y, 0, .45}, {x, 0, .45}]
```

which produced error messages suggesting that Mathematica tried to evaluate `ode` before inserting specific values for `x` and`y`.  Perhaps, someone else can address how to use `RegionPlot`, but `ContourPlot` seems to meet your need.

**Addendum**

Better is to use `ParametricNDSolve`, which is designed for such problems.

```
odep = ParametricNDSolve[{Dt[lh[t], t] == lh[t]^2 + (1/8) ls[t]^2 - 3/8, 
  Dt[ls[t], t] == 2 ls[t]^2 + lh[t]^2/8, lh[10] == lh0, ls[10] == ls0}, 
  {lh, ls}, {t, 10, 40}, {lh0, ls0}]
```

Then,

```
ContourPlot[(lh[x, y] /. odep)[11], {y, 0, .45}, {x, 0, .45}, Contours -> {-1, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{z}, Hue[.3 (1 + Sign[z])]]]
```

produces the same plot as above, and `RegionPlot` also works.

```
RegionPlot[((lh[x, y] /. odep)[11]) > 0, {y, 0, .45}, {x, 0, .45}]
```

[image: Region Plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help.Cheers and Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: Could you explain exactly how did you use where lh[x,y], in RegionPlot, where lh has been defined as lh[t] and in ((lh[x, y] /. odep)[11]) > 0 , what does [11] stand for? Thanks!

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve` produces `ParametricFunction`s, described in the Mathematica documentation.  `lh[x, y] /. odep` evaluates `lh` for parameters `{x, y}` provided by the plot routines, converting `lh` to an `InterpolatingFunction`.  Finally, `[11]` at the end evaluates it at `t = 11`.  `RegionPlot` and `ContourPlot` can display `lh` only at a specific point in time, and I chose eleven arbitrarily within the domain that the solution was valid.  Does this help?  By the way, please Accept my Answer above, if it meets your needs.  Best wishes.