# Bug in plotting function using FindMinimum?

Tags: plotting, bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

While working on an answer to [RegionPlot from NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/regionplot-from-ndsolve), I came across this strange behavior of `RegionPlot` and `ParametricPlot` involving a function that sometimes called `FindMinimum`.  Below is a simplified version of the code, and in it the function `lhmin` always calls `FindMinimum`.

I'm thinking it is probably a bug. However, I wonder if I'm breaking a rule somewhere, and something I'm doing is causing this apparent bug.  The following is the complete code, run on a new kernel.  I'm using V10.0.1 (on Mac OSX 10.9.5).

```
ode3[y_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := Block[{t},
  First@NDSolve[{
     Dt[lh[t], t] == -ls[t]/2 - (lh[t] - 1)^3/4,
     Dt[ls[t], t] == lh[t]/2 - ls[t]^3,
     lh[0] == y, ls[0] == M}, {lh, ls}, {t, 0, 40}]]

lhmin[y0_?NumericQ, M0_?NumericQ] := With[{sol = ode3[y0, M0]},
   With[{values = lh["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol},
    Print[{y0, M0}];
    With[{minPos = First@Ordering[values, 1]},
     First@FindMinimum[{lh[t] /. sol, {0 <= t <= 40}},
       {t, (lh["Coordinates"] /. sol)[[1, minPos]]}]
     ]]
   ];
```

Note that `lhmin` prints its input before calling `FindMinimum`.  You will note below that it does not produce a slew of output, because the whole thing pretty quickly comes to a halt because of an uncaught `Throw`.

**`RegionPlot`.**  In this plot, `lhmin` is used to define the region.  There are messages about `Break[]` being abused and some delinquent function acting up and throwing things.

```
RegionPlot[lhmin[y, M] > 0, {y, 0.1, 1.}, {M, 0, 10}]
```

> ```
> {0.10004741578947368`, 0.0005268421052631579`}  (* output of Print *)
> {0.10000004736842105`, 5.263157894736842`*^-7}
> {0.10000004736842105`, 5.263157894736842`*^-7}
> ```
>
> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]. >>
>
> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]. >>
>
> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of Break::nofwd will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> FindMinimum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations. The best estimated solution, with feasibility residual, KKT residual, or complementary residual of {0.0423358,2.58505*10^-10,0.0211679}, is returned. >>
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[{{8.34096},{0.0635038,{0.0423358,2.58505*10^-10,0.0211679}},500,NOTCONVERGED},FindMinimum`InteriorPoint] returned to top level. >>
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null,FindMinimum`InteriorPoint] returned to top level. >>

```
(* Hold[Throw[{{8.34096}, {0.0635038, {0.0423358, 2.58505*10^-10, 
       0.0211679}}, 500, "NOTCONVERGED"}, FindMinimum`InteriorPoint], 
    Throw[Null, FindMinimum`InteriorPoint]] *)
```

However, note that evaluating the function `lhmin` on the point indicated works fine and without generating messages.

```
lhmin @@ {0.10000004736842105`, 5.263157896957288`*^-7}
```

> ```
> {0.1,5.26316*10^-7}   (* output of Print *)
> ```

```
(*  0.0913811  *)
```

**`ParametricPlot`.**  I used `lhmin` in the `RegionFunction` to `ParametricPlot`, and it generates the same messages as above except no `FindMinimum::eit`, perhaps because `FindMinimum` did not have a convergence problem on the particular input `` {0.1`, 0.`} ``.  The output is different, but that's probably not significant, since it's a different function.

```
ParametricPlot[{y, M}, {y, 0.1, 1.}, {M, 0, 10}, 
  RegionFunction -> (lhmin[#1, #2] > 0 &)]
```

> ```
> {0.1`, 0.`}   (* output of Print *)
> ```
>
> Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]. >>
>   ...
>   Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[{{8.34095},{0.0635036,{0.0423357,3.05593*10^-10,0.0211679}},500,NOTCONVERGED},FindMinimum`InteriorPoint] returned to top level. >>
>
> Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Null,FindMinimum`InteriorPoint] returned to top level. >>

```
Hold[Break[], Break[], <<7499>>, Throw[Null, FindMinimum`InteriorPoint]]
```

Again evaluating the function `lhmin` on the point indicated works fine and without generating messages.

```
lhmin @@ {0.1`, 0.`}
```

> {0.1,0.}

```
(*  0.0913811  *)
```

**Summary.**  On the one hand `lhmin` and `FindMinimum` work without a problem when called by themselves.  On the other hand, when `lhmin` is called from within `RegionPlot` or `ParametricPlot`, `FindMinimum` seems to generate fatal errors (on the same input values) that kill the program.  Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

---

*Confirmed by WRI.*

Comment: When I used `NDSolve` on the question you cited in your first line, I too encountered a problem with `RegionPlot`, although I am uncertain whether it was the same problem.  For this reason, I also used `ContourPlot`.  In any case, the problem went away, when I used `ParameterNDSolve`.

Comment: No (obvious) problem on version 9.0.1, with no messages produced after about 10 minutes of run-time. So, I think it looks like a possible bug in version 10. I don't have that installed on this computer, I'm not feeling patient enough to let version 9 run to completion, and also not much in the mood for troubleshooting, so this is of course not conclusive, but clearly we should not be seeing `FindMinimum`'s throw come back to the top level. I'd report it, if I were you.

Comment: This is most certainly a bug. I can only emphasize what Olek mentioned at the end: A `Throw` inside a built-in function should never reach the user. This would be very bad style. Btw, I get the same output as you did on Linux 64 with *Mathematica* 10.0.2.

Comment: As suggested in my previous comment, I had hoped that using `ParametricNDSolve` with `RegionPlot` might provide better results.  It did not, instead producing much the same errors described above.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for checking.  That's rather what I expected, since I think `ParametricNDSolve` is basically a nice user interface to `NDSolve`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sorry about that - my original `lhmin` only rarely called `FindMinimum`.  I didn't think about it actually working and running for a good long time.  As far as I can tell, on V10, it fails in the first few calls.  Thanks for checking V9.  P.S. I have reported it and will update when I hear back.

Comment: With version 11, the error messages do not appear, perhaps because the kernel soon crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, this is a bug.

For a possible workaround, try

```
RegionPlot[lhmin[y, M] > 0, {y, 0.1, 1.}, {M, 0, 10}, "NumericalFunction" -> False]
```

Some related questions: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94402), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79572/regionplot-returning-a-number), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99878/workaround-for-using-nminimize-inside-regionplot).