# error with NIntegrate and RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 10.2 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
RegionPlot[
  NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}] >= 0.2,
                {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]
```

(yes, it doesn't depend on `x`)

This returns an inscrutable error:

```
Throw::nocatch: "Uncaught \!\(Throw[\(-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x]\)
+ \*SuperscriptBox[\"Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y\", \"\[Prime]\",
MultilineFunction->None][NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x],
NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation]\) returned to top level."
```

I'm using Mathematica 10.2. Any ideas what's wrong?

EDIT: I'm not looking for algebraic simplifications or substituting `Integrate` for `NIntegrate`. The above code is just an example to reproduce the error. In the code I actually want to run, `NIntegrate` is the only option.

Comment: Have you tried to figure out where the error come from? To izolate the problem try divide and conquer approach first...

Comment: I can reproduce that error with 10.1, even defining a pure numeric function to pass to `RegionPlot`.  The `NIntegrate` by itself works fine. B-G?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in `RegionPlot`. For a possible workaround, try the following undocumented option

```
RegionPlot[NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}] >= 0.2, 
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}, "NumericalFunction" -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I cannot find documentation of the option `"NumericalFunction"` for `RegionPlot` nor `Graphics`

Comment: It seems that 11.3 introduces additional error `NIntegrate::nlim: a = y is not a valid limit of integration.` and also the bug is still not solved, any idea that why the new error shows up?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT : Changed for your edited question

```
$Version

(* "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)
```

Define a helper function that is defined only for numeric arguments

```
f[y_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[
   PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a],
   {a, 0, y}];

rgn = ImplicitRegion[
   f[y] >= 0.2 && -1 <= x <= 1 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.7,
   {x, y}];
```

However, this is very sloo...oow

```
RegionPlot[rgn, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {0.1, 0.7}}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

`ContourPlot` is much, much faster

```
f[0.62] >= 0.2

(* True *)

ContourPlot[f[y],
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7},
   Contours -> {0.2},
   Epilog -> Text["f[y] \[GreaterEqual] 0.2", {0, 0.62}]] //
  AbsoluteTiming // Column
```

[image]

---

The largest that your integral can be is for `y = 0.7`

```
dist = NormalDistribution[0, 1];

Integrate[PDF[dist, a], {a, 0, 0.7}]

(* 0.258036 *)
```

This is equivalent to

```
CDF[dist, 0.7] - CDF[dist, 0]

(* 0.258036 *)
```

Even if you were to integrate from `-Infinity`, the largest that the integral could be is

```
Integrate[PDF[dist, a], {a, -Infinity, 0.7}]

(* 0.758036 *)
```

or equivalently,

```
CDF[dist, 0.7] - CDF[dist, -Infinity]

(* 0.758036 *)
```

or more simply

```
CDF[dist, 0.7]

(* 0.758036 *)
```

Consequently, since you are looking for the region for which the integral is greater than or equal to `0.95`, your region is empty. Note the use of `Integrate` rather than `NIntegrate`

```
RegionPlot[
 Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}] >= 0.95, {x, -1, 
  1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]
```

[image]

If you reverse the inequality then

```
RegionPlot[
 Integrate[PDF[dist, a], {a, 0, y}] < 0.95, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]
```

[image]

Or the same result with

```
RegionPlot[CDF[dist, y] - CDF[dist, 0] < 0.95, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]
```

Comment: be that as it may, we shouldn't expect an "inscrutable" error message.

Comment: Yes, it has nothing to do with `NormalDistribution`, `CDF` or `PDF`. Try `RegionPlot[NIntegrate[Sin[a], {a, 0, y}] >= 0.95, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]` vs `RegionPlot[NIntegrate[a, {a, 0, y}] >= 0.95, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]`.

Comment: Thanks for this, though substituting ``Integrate`` for ``NIntegrate`` isn't an option for me. See my edited post.

Answer (score 2):

Try this small variation over your original request

```
   RegionPlot[
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, x}] > 0.3 // 
  Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: doesn't work on v9 :(

Comment: `Release` .. had to look that up, superseded in version 2 (1991!).   (`Evaluate` works as well )

Comment: @george2079 oops… I am old and I forget :-) Then against does the job!

Answer (score 1):

While the behavior has already been confirmed a bug -- an uncaught `Throw` from an internal function must always be one, right? -- here are a couple more workarounds.

*How I analyze the problem of finding a workaround*: From the context `` NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump` `` in the error message, one might infer that `NIntegrate` is trying to determine whether to use (or even using) [`"LevinRule"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html) for the integration method.  Since it's for oscillatory integrands, it doesn't seem that appropriate.  Probably it is occurring during the `"SymbolicProcessing"` phase of `NIntegrate`.  And if not, we could pick an integration rule manually.

```
RegionPlot[
  NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}] >= 
   0.2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RegionPlot[
   NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}] >= 
    0.2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Turning off symbolic processing is fastest, but you lose automatic method selection for certain types of integral such as when the integrand is oscillatory.  By comparison, [ilian's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) mystery option `"NumericalFunction" -> False` takes about as long as picking the `"GaussKronrodRule"` explicitly.  For some reason, this method does not produce a spurious error message (which comes from `RegionPlot` evaluating the argument symbolically).

```
RegionPlot[
   NIntegrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], a], {a, 0, y}] >= 0.2,
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0.1, 0.7}, 
   "NumericalFunction" -> False]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

All produce plots that look the same:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is a good approach to analyze the problem (I upvoted). I would like to point out that singularity handling for one dimensional integrals is not switched off by "SymbolicProcessing"->0. That is done with the option setting "SingularityHandler" -> None in the integration strategy methods.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the correction. I hope the update is more accurate. (And thanks for the upvote.)