# RegionPlot evaluating NIntegrate before assigning variable values and resulting in non-numerical integrands

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, bugs, warning-messages

I am trying to find the regions where the integral of a function a function is larger than a certain quantity using RegionPlot. For simplicity's sake, let's say the intergal I am looking to plot is is

```
F[x_, y_, s_] := NIntegrate[Exp[(x - y)^2/(2*s^2)], {x, -3, 3}];
```

If I then attempt to plot this using RegionPlot using this code

```
RegionPlot[F[x, y, s] > 100, {y, -3, 3}, {s, 0.1, 2}]
```

I get the following error message

```
NIntegrate: The integrand E^((x-y)^2/(2 s^2)) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-3,3}}.
```

followed by throwing an exception

```
Throw: "Uncaught\!\(Throw[\(-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`\LevinRuleDump`x]\) + \\*SuperscriptBox[\"Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y\", \"\\[Prime]\",MultilineFunction->None][NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x], \NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation]\) \ returned to top level."
```

So it seems that RegionPlot is actually trying to evaluate F before assigning values to y and s and this is causing NIntegrate to crash. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Use [_?NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) on `F[]`

Comment: Oops, I should have first asked, what numeric value is assigned to `x` in your `RegionPlot[]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 That was a mistake, I shouldn't have defined it with x in this example and I wasn't initializing it with anything, but removing x didn't affect the result. Apparently what was missing was the undocumented NumericalFunction option pointed out in the answer below

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183631/using-regionplot-with-nintegrate-causes-symbolic-evaluation-when-integrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `F without x-argument`

```
F[ y_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[Exp[(x - y)^2/(2*s^2)], {x, -3, 3}];
```

ContourPlot evaluates the region boundary `F[ y, s] ==100`

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[F[ y, s]] == 100, {y, -3, 3}, {s, 0.1, 2}, FrameLabel -> {y, s}]
```

[image]

No idea why RegionPlot fails. As a **workaround** use Plot3D and RegionFunction

```
 pic = Plot3D[0 , {y, -3, 3}, {s, 0.1, 2},RegionFunction ->  Function[{y, s, z}, F[y, s] > 100],Mesh -> False]
```

Now change `Graphics3D-> Graphics`

```
arg = pic[[1]] /. GraphicsComplex -> List; (* argument of GraphicsComplex*)
Graphics[Apply[GraphicsComplex, {Map[ Most[#] &, arg[[1]]], Rest[arg]}],Axes -> True]
```

[image]

**final** 
RegionPlot with undocumented option

```
RegionPlot[F[y, s] > 100, {y, -3, 3}, {s, 0.1, 2}, "NumericalFunction" -> False]
```

[image]

That's it!

Comment: The NumericalFunction option worked like a charm!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Source for the `"NumericalFunction"` option (@ilian): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/error-with-nintegrate-and-regionplot/94471#94471